# Is there an adverb for "quickly at first, slowly later"?

Tags: adverbs

When water comes out of a faucet at the bottom of a tank, it comes out quickly first and then it tapers off. Is there an adverb for such a case?

Comment: This seems like a very complex idea for a single word (not that words don't encode complex ideas, just... I don't see this one seeing enough use to become part of the language). I can think of a few that describe the process of diminishing volume, but not that it began with a flood and ended in a trickle. This is the sort of thing usually left to clauses.

Comment: Apparently we need tunable adverbs.

Comment: The verb - `to peter out`? Not dissimilar from taper off, I realise.

Comment: And diminishing.

Comment: One Google result for _deacceleratingly_: 'the universe expands deacceleratingly'. I've heard people say that _if it's been used, it's a word_. I wouldn't use it unless I wanted a whimsical effect.

Answer (score 2):

Let's face it, there is no unclumsy adverb for this. Go with a verb. The stream *dies off, loses momentum, dries up* are all possible. So is your very own *tapers off*, and the *peters out* suggested in a comment. The pressure *drops down*. Custom-tailored, more colorful metaphors are possible as well, like *loses dedication, gets lazy, gives up*, or any number of others. Try as you might, you won't get that kind of flexibility with an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

How about "sinkingly," as in "[Snow falls down sinkingly](http://langueaddict.tumblr.com/post/36056745953/special-posting-poetry-of-baek-seok)?"

[Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sink)

[Webster](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=Sink&quicksearch=on)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few phrases that get close to this meaning but the more accurate terms are somewhat technical.

> [decreasingly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/decreasingly?s=t) — becoming less or fewer; diminishing.
>
> logarithmically — something that changes according to [logarithmic growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_growth)

The major issue with these terms is that they sound weird and the meanings are not very clear:

> The decreasingly escaping water.
>
> The water is escaping logarithmically.

A more understandable phrasing would specifically refer to the rate being described:

> The water pressure decreases quickly.
>
> The faucet releases water at a decreasing rate.

Answer (score 0):

[Diminishingly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diminishingly) seems to fit the bill.